# Android WebView

Tags: android

Hi
 my application using a webview ,when the webpage contain a  particular text i want to start a new activity,is it possible?

Comment: By webpage, you mean the whole page of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Use UrLConnection class to retrive web site content
2.Check whether the particular data is there, then start new activity
3.webview.loadData(content, "text/html", "utf-8");